# SAML in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, saml

I need to implement SAML in web based Delphi 2010 application. Are there any components available in Delphi 2010 to implement?Are there any delphi sample code available? 
I could see sample code for .net but not for Delphi Please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Similar question: [Delphi & SAML (Web apps or desktop apps)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764245/delphi-saml-web-apps-or-desktop-apps)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the link.That question was particular about desktop applications (AD) But I need to do for WEB based delphi application

Answer (score 1):

I have had a look around the web, as far as I am able to tell, delphi 2010 doesn't have a component for the implementation of SAML.
The most helpful website I have been able to find is this: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.non-tech/saml-in-delphi-2010/1087146 (Link leads out of stack overflow) but as far as I can tell delphi has no components for it, Sorry!